# Could someone tell me why this code isn't working?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database

So I have been stuck with this for a long time now, unable to figure why it isn't working. This is a registration page which, after submitting information, should upload the information (the one I choose, not all the registration options enter the database) into a table (called tbl) inside the database (known as Database2.mdf). This is through Visual Studio 2010. There is also a java phase that checks the information but I don't think that is what is causing the problem so I'll just post the SQL code and the HTML code, along with the names of the table lines.

The SQL bit:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["sub"] != null)
    {
        string fName = Request.Form["FName"];
        string lName = Request.Form["LName"];
        string uName = Request.Form["UName"];
        string Street = Request.Form["Street"];
        string City = Request.Form["City"];
        string Pass = Request.Form["Password"];
        string PassCon = Request.Form["PasswordConf"];
        string Email = Request.Form["Email"];
        string Comments = Request.Form["Comment"];
        int ID = int.Parse(Request.Form["ID"]);
        string conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        string cmdStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO tbl (FirstName, LastName, UserName, Street, City, Password, PasswordConfirm, Email, Comments, IdentificationNumber) VALUES  (N'{0}', N'{1}', N'{2}', N'{3}', N'{4}', N'{5}', N'{6}', N'{7}', N'{8}', {9})", fName, lName, uName, Street, City, Pass, PassCon, Email, Comments, ID);
        SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmdObj = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conObj);
        conObj.Open();
        cmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conObj.Close();
    }

}
</script>
```

The HTML bit: (CheckForm is the name of the Javassript action that checks if the form matches the requirements, also Registration.aspx is the registration page obviously, and it is not linked to a master page)

```
<form action="Registration.aspx" method="post" name="ContactForm"
onsubmit="return CheckForm()">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" size="65" name="FName" />
    <br />
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" size="65" name="LName" />
    <br />
    Username:
    <input type="text" size="65" name="UName" />
    <br />
    Street:
    <input type="text" size="65" name="Street" />
    <br />
    City:
    <input type="text" size="65" name="City" />
    <br />
    Password:
    <input type="password" size="65" name="Password" />
    <br />
    Password Confimration:
    <input type="password" size="65" name="PasswordConf" />
    <br />
    E-mail Address:
    <input type="text" size="65" name="Email" />
    <br />
    Comments:
    <input type="text" size="100" name="Comment" />
    <br />
    Identification Number:
    <input type="password" size="65" name="ID" />
    <br />
    Mobile :
    <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" style="width: 40px;" maxlength="3" />
    -
    <input type="text" name="mobile1" maxlength="7" />
    <br />
    Gender: Male<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_Male" value="Male" checked />
    Female<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_Female" value="Female" />
    <br />
    Which countries would you like to recieve political news for?:
    <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='files[]' id='1' value='1' />
    Israel
    <input type='checkbox' name='files[]' id='2' value='2' />
    Russia
    <input type='checkbox' name='files[]' id='3' value='3' />
    Canada
    <br />
    How often do you read the newspaper?
    <br />
    <select id="cardtype" name="sel">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Never</option>
        <option value="2">Everyday</option>
        <option value="3">Once a week</option>
        <option value="4">Once a year</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    What can we help you with?
    <select type="text" value="" name="Subject">
        <option></option>
        <option>Customer Service</option>
        <option>Question</option>
        <option>Comment</option>
        <option>Consultation</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" />
    </form>
```

The table lines are as follows:

- FirstName - nvarchar(50)
- LastName - nvarchar(50)
- UserName - nvarchar(50)
- Street - nvarchar(50)
- City - nvarchar(50)
- Password - nvarchar(50)
- PasswordConfirm - nvarchar(50)
- Email - nvarchar(50)
- Comments - nvarchar(50) - Only one that allows nulls
- IdentificationNumber - int

I know this is A LOT to sift through but I have been stuck with it for so long and I must get it fixed very quickly, I would VERY much appreciate any help provided! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the browser debugger to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the amount of sifting that must be done.

The first thing that I would do is run the in browser debugger and see what errors pop up. Then, add those errors to this question.

Along with that information, what have you tried? What haven't you tried yet?

From what I have seen on this and other forums is that when you ask a question the more detailed you are with what you have and haven't tried, and with what the program is supposed to do, you get more detailed and helpful answers faster.

p.s. People don't want to waste their time answering a badly worded or vague question. So, being descriptive really helps.